# Npm install takes more than 2 hours when running "npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

configured node v16.17.0 in my machine(windows).

This is my package.json, when am try to run "npm install" it takes more than 2 hours

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "shelljs":"0.8.5",
    "typo-js":"1.2.2",
    "simple-git":"3.15.0",
    "markdownlint":"0.26.2",
    "run-sequence":"2.2.1",
    "request-promise":"4.2.6",
    "single-line-log":"1.1.2",
    "ajv": "6.12.3",
    "aws-sdk": "2.1248.0",
    "require-dir":"1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries": "4.24.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.7.1",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.12",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "eslint": "8.27.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.10",
    "loader-utils":"3.2.1",
    "gatsby": "4.24.0",
    "gatsby-cli": "4.24.0",
    "gatsby-link": "4.24.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "2.0.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-remove-generator": "1.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-client-side-redirect": "0.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "2.0.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls": "1.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "4.24.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "3.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "4.24.0",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "2.0.11",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "2.0.6",
    "gatsby-remark-external-links": "0.0.4",
    "gatsby-remark-image-attributes": "1.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "3.0.3",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "2.0.6",
    "node-gyp":"9.3.0",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "2.0.6",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "4.21.0-next.3",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "2.1.5",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "5.24.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "4.24.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "markdown-spellcheck":"0.11.0",
    "gulp-jshint":"2.1.0",
    "gulp-htmllint":"0.0.19",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-typography": "0.16.13"
  }
}
```

i checked this [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283) to run "npm set progress=false" to speed up progress also taking same time. i specified the few of these depdencies`(var shelljs = require('shelljs'))` directly in my js files of my project folder which was throwing shelljs module not found so that i moved those kind of depdencies inside the packages.json(shelljs,gulp-gzip..etc).

Anyone have idea to reduce the time taken for npm install commands?

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to your environment, maybe very slow internet connection or weak performance of your PC. 
I've tried to install the same list of dependencies and it  took a few minutes to run (Macbook Pro 2019, 16GB RAM, macOS Monterey, node 16.17.0, npm 8.15.0, 100Mbps connection)

Comment: In my machine, npm was 8.15.0 and 16gb ram windows 64 bit. Also, download speed was good(22 Mbps(speedtest.net))